# Get only several data using realtime update firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, real-time-updates

Get only several data at first load using listener for realtime update in firestore. When i using limit (example: 15 data), after those data the listener won't get another data for realtime update.

Get only 15 data at first load and only listen to new data added